# How to add include rule for other directory?

Tags: build, cmake

I have this directory structure :

```
- code
  - shared lib 1
    - unit tests
  - shared lib 2
    - unit tests
- extern libs
  - gtest + gmock
  - extern lib
```

Each directory has one CMakeLists.txt file.

Shared library 2 needs to link shared library 2. This I solved, how to solve the include?

Here are my CMakeList.txt files for shared lib 1 :

```
SET( LIB_OUTPUT_NAME shlib1 )

FILE (GLOB HEADER_FILES ./*.hpp)
FILE (GLOB SOURCE_FILES ./*.cpp)

ADD_LIBRARY (${LIB_OUTPUT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES} )
```

and for shared lib 2 :

```
SET( LIB_OUTPUT_NAME shlib2 )

# what to put here? this doesn't work
include_directories(${shlib1})

FILE( GLOB HEADER_FILES ./*.hpp )
FILE( GLOB SOURCE_FILES ./*.cpp )

ADD_LIBRARY( ${LIB_OUTPUT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES} )

target_link_libraries( ${LIB_OUTPUT_NAME} shlib1 )
```

PS: I got more libraries - not just 2. That is why I am looking at more generic solution.

---

I tried to use [target_include_directories](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3atarget_include_directories) like this :

```
target_include_directories( ${LIB_OUTPUT_NAME} PUBLIC ${shlib1} )
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using CMake v2.8.11 or newer, then [`target_include_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/command/target_include_directories.html) is indeed the way to go.

It's not clear from your question *which* CMakeLists.txt you've added this command to.  If you're trying to specify that any target which depends on `shlib1` should have "code/shared lib 1" as an include search path, then you should add the command to "code/shared lib 1/CMakeLists.txt".

In your `target_include_directories` call, you're specifying that the public search path should be `${shlib1}`.  I expect that this variable is actually empty - you're certainly not setting it anywhere in your example code.  What *is* available however is the variable `shlib1` - this is the target created in your `add_library` call, but it's not too useful here.

So, your command in "code/shared lib 1/CMakeLists.txt" should be something like:

```
target_include_directories(${LIB_OUTPUT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

If you don't want to use `target_include_directories` (or have to cater for older versions of CMake), you would have to use [`include_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/command/include_directories.html) in "code/shared lib 2/CMakeLists.txt".  However, you'd have to pass the path to "code/shared lib 1".

You *could* just use a relative path but this perhaps isn't the most robust solution:

```
include_directories("../shared lib 1")
```

or assuming you have your top-level CMakeLists.txt in "code", you could do:

```
include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/shared lib 1")
```

but this isn't much better.

A more robust option might be to make each subdirectory a separate project (i.e. have a [`project`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/command/project.html) call at the top of each subdir's CMakeLists.txt).  This makes the variable `<projectName>_SOURCE_DIR` available to all subsequent CMake files.  So, if your first shared lib also had `project(sharedlib1)`, then in "code/shared lib 2/CMakeLists.txt" you could do:

```
include_directories(${sharedlib1_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Or another reasonable solution would be to set a cache variable (to make it available everywhere) in every subdir's CMakeLists.txt, specifying that subdir's public search path(s).  For example, in "code/shared lib 1/CMakeLists.txt":

```
set(shlib1_includes "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" CACHE INTERNAL
    "Public include path(s) for shlib1")
```

then in "code/shared lib 2/CMakeLists.txt":

```
include_directories(${shlib1_includes})
```